# How to make card rounded shape in react native, native base

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm using the native base components on top of react native and I was wondering how to get the cards be round instead of rectangular in the UI.
Is there a rounded prop for that?

Comment: Have you tried `borderRadius` style property ? I have no prior experience with native base but `borderRadius` is react native's style property to give rounded corners. So if you have a square of 40x40 you should give `borderRadius: 20` to get a complete circle. Hope that helps.

Comment: Tried that out, did not work :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, no one actually could answer this, but somehow luckily on github I found this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Header, Title, Content, Button, Icon, Card, CardItem, Text, Body, Left, Right, IconNB, View } from "native-base";
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      loading: true
     };
  }
  static navigationOptions = {
    header:null
  };

  async componentWillMount() {
    await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf"),
      Roboto_medium: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf"),
      Ionicons: require("@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf"),
    });
    this.setState({ loading: false });
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <Expo.AppLoading />;
    }
    else
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header>
          <Left>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon name="arrow-back" />
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Title>Header</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right />
        </Header>
        <Content padder>
          <Card style={{ borderRadius: 8 }}>
            <CardItem header bordered style={{ borderTopLeftRadius: 8, borderTopRightRadius: 8 }}>
              <Text>NativeBase</Text>
            </CardItem>
            <CardItem bordered>
              <Body>
                <Text>
                  NativeBase is a free and open source framework that enable
                  developers to build
                  high-quality mobile apps using React Native iOS and Android
                  apps
                  with a fusion of ES6.
                </Text>
              </Body>
            </CardItem>
            <CardItem bordered>
              <Body>
                <Text>
          NativeBase builds a layer on top of React Native that provides
                  you with
                  basic set of components for mobile application development.
                </Text>
              </Body>
            </CardItem>
            <CardItem bordered>
              <Body>
                <Text>
                  Get on the mobile fast track with NativeBase, the
                  fastest-growing platform
                  and tool set for iOS and Android development.
                </Text>
              </Body>
            </CardItem>
            <CardItem footer bordered style={{ borderBottomLeftRadius: 8, borderBottomRightRadius: 8 }}>
              <Text>GeekyAnts</Text>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
        </Content>
      </Container >
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you akhil-geekyants!!!!
[Here](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1845) is the link to the original post

[Here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2468) is another link related to image as background in card with rounded corners

Comment: thank you very very much, was stuck on this for hours.

Answer (score -2):

The correct way is `<Card borderRadius={50}>`.

Source: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1845#issuecomment-409624785